# Building Information logistic application

Tags: owl, ontology, ilog, logistics

want to build an ILOG application, yielding to a demand driven information
supply of patients before, during and after a medical treatment. The application should
know certain content sources (e.g. health databases), know a user’s information demand
(e.g. from an electronic patient card), know the user’s location (e.g. at the clinic, at
home) and provide her/him with the information she/he needs (e.g. allergic information,
pharmacy services). Information supply can be passive (i.e. the user queries for
information) and active (i.e. information push by the system).
we need to deal with when we realize this application

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think, it is better to clean up coursework questions of references to lectures and that sort of thing. Otherwise, it becomes really obvious that you are just trying to get someone else to do your work for you.